# Cannot close OSX Cocoa app after sheet segue

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa

I have an OSX app with two views. Right now the segue between the two is a sheet segue.

Once I segue from view 1 to view 2, I can no longer close the window/app. The 'x' is disabled, and cmd-Q produces an error noise. This occurs after segueing back to the original view.

Any idea why this is happening? Is there something I should be calling in prepareForSegue?

(Also: every time I perform the sheet segue, a shadow builds around the perimeter of my window. I imagine this means I'm not correctly closing the original view?)

Comment: You've said it for youself in the title of the topic.  Just close the sheet.

Comment: Looks like your app starts a modal loop after opening the sheet. You are supposed to stop the modal loop in order to make the app responsive again. In code it could be done in several ways, one of them is `NSApp.stopModal()`

Comment: How do you go from view 2 to view 1? Does view 2 have buttons to close the sheet?

Comment: Can you include some screen shots demonstrating the various states mentioned in your question? Some code on how you present and subsequently dismiss the sheet would also be very helpful. Please include a screen shot clearly demonstrating the case when you cannot close the window, i.e. with the 'x' button disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make button x and connect with action:

```
self.dismissViewController(_:)
```

Answer (score 0):

There more than one type of segues.

1. Show: The show segue doesn't block your UI. Just makes another view, it can be used when you open something that be edited simultaneously with the current view (like different documents, or different views to the same document that the user wants to see and control both)
2. Modal: Modal is like a dialog box, which in most cases presents an question that ***must*** be answered to proceed with the same view, so it "blocks" the view that instantiated it. Like it asks you whether you want to close without saving, for example, it is not reasonable that you modify the document again, until you answer the question with no.
3. Sheet: Type of modal, but a different shape (It is like a dialog box,  for example: used for save and open).
4. Popover: You can consider it a type of "Show", it can be used to give information about the control instantiated it.

For more information:

Try to read [this guidelines about dialog boxes](https://developer.apple.com/macos/human-interface-guidelines/windows-and-views/dialogs/)

[Popovers](https://developer.apple.com/macos/human-interface-guidelines/windows-and-views/popovers/)